# Laravel 5.4 Embedding Inline Images

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 scheduler to send an email by embedding(not attaching) images to the view. In the documentation, it has been mentioned that we can pass a $message variable into the view and use

```
{{ $message->embed('path/to/the/file') }}
```

in the view file.

My code is

```
//SendUserReport.php ~ (It is a Command class)
public function handle(){
    \Mail::to($mailList)->send(new UserReport($data,$subscriber->id));
}

//UserReport.php ~ (It is a Mailable class)
public function build(){
    $data = $this->mailData;
    $id   = $this->id;
    return $this->view('mails.reports.user-report', compact('data',));
}
```

How should I pass the $message variable using the above logic?

For the time being, I am able to pass the message variable using the code below without passing the control to the Mailable class (UserReport.php)

```
//SendUserReport.php ~ (It is a Command class)
\Mail::send('mails.reports.user-report',compact('data'), function($message) use ($mailList){
   $message->to($mailList)->subject('User Report for '.date('d-m-Y'));
 })
```

This code works fine and does well for my need, but I want to implement using the Mailable class.

Comment: What's `GreetReport` ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i have edited it.

Comment: Seems to be a dicussion about this at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17629 and also a package linked in that message that allows markdown style image embedding at https://github.com/eduardokum/laravel-mail-auto-embed

Comment: Thanks for your input, basically I am not looking for markdown emails. I am using a simple view file.